# Using relationship without createing new object in database

Tags: php, symfony

I've created a controller in which i want to create object `expense` that has relationship ManyToOne with PaymentMethod. I want to use existing records as reference in new object `expense` what mentod i have to use? This is my code underneath:

`Controller`

```
$expense->setPaymentMethod(
            //Solution underneath adds new object to database that I don't want to have
            //$paymentMethod->setPaymentMethod('Card')
            //What to add here?
        );
        $expense->setBoughtDate($time);

        $this->entityManager->persist($expense);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
```

`Expense`

```
class Expense
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    #[Groups(["expense:list", "expense:item"])]
    private int $id;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: PaymentMethod::class, cascade: ['persist'])]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: true)]
    private ?PaymentMethod $paymentMethod = null;

//Getters and setters underneath
```

`PaymentMethod::class`

```
class PaymentMethod
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    
    private int $id;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 64)]
    private string $paymentMethod;
```

Edit:
I had to create PaymentMethodRepository and use it in `setPaymentMethod()` like this

```
$expense->setPaymentMethod(
            $this->paymentMethodRepository->findOneBy(['id'=> 5])
        );
```

Comment: Start by making PaymentMethod::paymentMethod unique so at least you get an error if duplicate methods get posted.  Then just retrieve the existing payment method instead of creating one.